# IOS OpenCV expected type

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, objective-c++

**Hello guys,**

I have been searched for my problem for a couple of hours and didn't found anything.
Here is the code from the documentation:

```
#pragma mark - Protocol CvVideoCameraDelegate

#ifdef __cplusplus
- (void)processImage:(Mat&)image
{
    // Do some OpenCV stuff with the image
}
#endif
```

So the problem is in the method declaration: "Expected a type". - (void)processImage:(Mat&)image

Anyone knows what is the problem?

Comment: Just a guess, but you will need to prefix the namespace `cv::Mat` if you don't have a `using namespace cv;` statement before your declaration.

Comment: amazing. thanks! can you put it as an answer and i will up you?